# Apply metarig armature to mesh

Tags: mesh, modifiers, rigging, armature

Is there any way to 'embedd' a pose from a metarig armature onto the connected mesh, so the armature can be applied/deleted without losing the pose? I'd like to do some dyntopo sculpting on a posed mesh, but of course those newly added polygons then won't be part of the rig and will mess up the model.
If I try to apply the armature mod, this message shows up: 'Modifyers cannot be applied to a mesh with shape keys'
Didn't find any solutions on google. Using 2.92
Any tips are much appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply all shape keys and then apply the armature modifier, or use this addon, to apply modifiers on mesh with shape keys.

https://github.com/przemir/ApplyModifierForObjectWithShapeKeys

Comment: Aaah thanks a ton! The plugin unfortunately didn't show up in any of my blender versions, neither with the usual way of installing, nor copying the folder directly into the blender core folder (which usually solved these problems), but the manual way works perfectly! Hope they fix that at some point

Comment: Do you actually MEAN to be referencing the META rig? You should NEVER be binding to the metarig. The purpose of the metarig is to generate the final rig, and then be deleted or placed aside. You should only be binding to the final rig.